# JS - How to clear interval after using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyone know how to kill interval after using `setInterval()` in the following use case?

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "test.php",
      success: function(result){
        $("#results").append(result);
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

**test.php**

```
$CT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
echo $CT;
```

Comment: What loop? You mean the interval "loop"?

Answer (score 23):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#results").append(result);
        }
    });
}, 1000);

clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Thanks @mmmshuddup, but there is nothing displayed on the page after using the code.

Comment: Well you're not supposed to `clearInterval()` _right away_.  How many times do you need that to run?

Comment: I get the feeling that you mean to use `setTimeout()` instead.  In which case, it would only run once and then you wouldn't need to clear anything..

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `clearInterval` function

```
    var interval = setInterval()....
    clearInterval(interval);
```

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 5):

Use clear interval method `clearInterval();` pass your variable in which you `setInterval`.

For example:

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(fname, 10000);

clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were planning on only running the function once, I would suggest using [Window SetTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) as it executes once, making clearing the interval after one run redundant.